# Why LeftDoubleClick does not work for a slider

Tags: wpf, slider, double-click

I have a slider that represents position in an audio file. The user requirement is to automatically play when the user double clicks on the slider.

When I use this:

```
<Slider.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />
</Slider.InputBindings>
```

The Play Command is not called. However, if I use this:

```
<Slider.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />
</Slider.InputBindings>
```

or this

```
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" (...)  MouseDoubleClick="slider1_MouseDoubleClick"  >
</Slider>
```

The play command is called.

What prevents the use of the gesture with the double click, yet allows the right click gesture or the double click event to be called?

Comment: looks like it's by design. You should copy the whole template file of the Slider control and try putting the `InputBindings` for the inner `Border` instead. This issue can also be encountered on many other controls, such as the `ListViewItem`, ...

Comment: Interesting... I wonder where that design decision comes from. It seems this is a rather common UI idiom...

Comment: yes, I in fact did not feel easy with such strange behavior. Such as in some cases the bubbling event can't be caught, so we cannot handle  the bubbling event, instead we have to handle the tunneling event (prefixed with `Preview`). In this case it's strange that `MouseDoubleClick` can be caught (I expected the `PreviewMouseDoubleClick`) while the corresponding mousebinding `LeftDoubleClick` cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I've figured out what's happening here:

The `RepeatButton` in the `Track` is intercepting the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event and setting `Handled = true`.  Note that the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event is an off-shoot of `MouseDown`, so if you set `Handled` for one, you're really setting it for both.  In this case, the mouse-down events are being handled when `ClickCount = 1`, and the act of marking the events as `Handled` prevents those events' handlers from being invoked on the second click (i.e., when `ClickCount = 2`).  Input gestures are evaluated on the `MouseDown` event, so suppressing the `MouseDown` handlers for the second click means the `Slider` won't get probed for input bindings, and commands with double-click gestures will never get a chance to execute.

So, if the mouse-down handlers don't get invoked during the second click, why do the `MouseDoubleClick` handlers get invoked?  Well, it turns out that `MouseDoubleClick` originates from a class-level handler in `Control`, and that handler gets invoked **even when the original mouse-down event(s) were marked as `Handled`**.  Note the last argument to `RegisterClassHandler` below:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
    typeof(Control),
    UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleDoubleClick),
    /* handledEventsToo: */ true);
```

And thus the `MouseDoubleClick` event gets raised even though the `LeftDoubleClick` input binding never got a chance to execute.  This is perhaps not the most intuitive behavior, and I'm unsure whether it was a conscious design decision or a simple oversight.